# Turn a String into an Anchor with jQuery

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, anchor

The second part of the code below listens to when Google Map markers are clicked and adds the URL to the address bar. How to I get this to instead wrap traditional anchor tags around the urls? e.g. < a href='#test2'>< /a>

```
        markers[1] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: sainsburys,
            url: '#test2',
            title: 'Sainsburys',
            map: map
        });


        for ( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
            window.location.href = this.url;
            });
        }
```

Full example is here http://jsfiddle.net/BQzLq/8/, although you can't see it working properly because JSFiddle won't allow the URL to be modified.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Perhaps I should try and be more explicit. At the moment when you click an icon Google Maps modifies the URL. I want it instead to wrap anchor tags around the markers so that I'm able to use a plugin which targets anchor tags to smooth scroll (http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html)

Comment: You can see an example of what I'm trying to achieve here - http://www.jaygeorge.co.uk/the-granary-barn/local-area/ - If you click the 'test' link above the red square you'll see that it smoothly scrolls to the blue square but clicking any of the map icons will 'jump' instead

Comment: Ive updated my answer. Does this make sense? Inhibit the browser from doing anything when a marker is clicked, and then you call the scrollto plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the `window.location.hash` property. Manipulating this directly does not cause the browser to scroll, but if you then call call `$.localScroll.hash()`, it might behave as you want.

[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location)

Comment: Jonas thanks for your suggestion, that sounds good. However I'm afraid you are going to have to spell it out with code, I'm pretty new to this and couldn't write it myself.

Comment: It's difficult with jsfiddle stopping url manipulation, but spelled out in this http://jsfiddle.net/CAD78/1/ fiddle.

Comment: Wow, it was really that simple! I've been scratching my head for hours with this. Thanks a lot Jonas, you're a hero :-). Here it is working http://www.jaygeorge.co.uk/the-granary-barn/local-area     - thank you to everyone else for your suggestions as well.

Comment: Good to hear! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This method uses a temp `<div>` and `innerHTML`, but you could completely create the `A` element with [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) calls if you wanted.

```
// create anchor
var anchorHtml = "<a href='" + this.url + "'>ANCHOR TEXT</a>";
var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
tempDiv.innerHTML = anchorHtml;
var anchor = tempDiv.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

// use anchor
document.body.appendChild(anchor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a div below the map:

```
    <div id="linkArea">
    </div>
```

then you can inject your Anchors into that:

```
    var anchor = '<a href="' + this.url + '">' + this.title + '</a><br/>';
    $('#linkArea').append(anchor);
```

The result is you should see your anchors appear where ever you locate the div.